# Get rendered html from another page in directive in angular.js 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, jquery-keditor

So my question is very tricky and non-conventional but I could not find any workaround for that.
I have used [kEditor](https://github.com/Kademi/keditor), a very powerful plugin for building template through drag and drop. The plugin was built in jquery. So I have created the directive to work with Keditor function.

I am using this plugin as it is open source and the best I could find on internet.

I have changed many of its coding. It provides only two tabs in side bar as in this link:
https://rawgit.com/Kademi/keditor/master/examples/callbacks.html

But in my case I am trying to build an invoice using this powerful tool. 
I have created some html and I need to insert that in to third tab as :
[image]

In my controller I am preparing html for that:

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$compile', 'loaderService', function ($scope, $compile, loaderService) {

    $scope.init = function () {
        loaderService.getJSON().then(function (callBack) {
            $scope.invoice = callBack.data.invoice;
        });
    }

    $scope.templateIntegration = function () {

        var template = '<div data-classification="invoice" data-type="component-{{invoice.invoiceNo.type}}" data-title="{{invoice.invoiceNo.label}}" data-length="{{invoice.invoiceNo.length}}" data-default-mask="{{invoice.invoiceNo.defaultMask}}" data-categories="Text;Dynamic component">' +
                        '<p>{{invoice.invoiceNo.value}}</p>' +
                        '</div>';

        template += '<div data-classification="invoice" data-type="component-{{invoice.invoiceDate.type}}" data-title="{{invoice.invoiceNo.label}}" data-default-mask="{{invoice.invoiceNo.label}}" data-categories="Text;Dynamic component">' +
                    '<p>{{invoice.invoiceDate.value}}</p>' +
                    '</div>';

        template += '<div data-classification="invoice" data-type="component-{{invoice.invoiceStatus.type}}" data-title="{{invoice.invoiceStatus.label}}" data-length="{{invoice.invoiceStatus.length}}" data-categories="Text;Dynamic component">' +
                    '<p>{{invoice.invoiceStatus.value}}</p>' +
                    '</div>';

        template += '<div data-classification="invoice" data-type="component-{{invoice.customer.name.type}}" data-title="{{invoice.customer.name.label}}" data-length="{{invoice.customer.name.length}}" data-categories="Text;Dynamic component">' +
            '<p>{{invoice.customer.name.value}}</p>' +
        '</div>';

        template += '<div data-classification="invoice" data-type="component-{{invoice.customer.address.type}}" data-title="{{invoice.customer.address.label }}" data-length="{{invoice.customer.address.length}}" data-categories="Text;Dynamic component">' +
            '<p>{{invoice.customer.address.value}}</p>' +
        '</div>';

        template += '<div data-classification="invoice" data-type="component-{{invoice.items.type}}" data-title="{{invoice.items.label }}" data-categories="Text;Dynamic component">' +
                    '<table class="table-striped table-responsive">' +
                    '<thead>' +
                        '<tr>' +
                        '<th>Name</th>' +
                        '<th>Price</th>' +
                        '<th>Tax</th>' +
                        '<th>Quantity</th>' +
                        '<th>Subtotal</th>' +
                        '</tr>' +
                    '</thead>' +
                    '<tbody>' +
                    '<tr ng-repeat="x in invoice.items.value">' +
                        '<td>{{x.name}}</td>' +
                        '<td>{{x.price}}</td>' +
                        '<td>{{x.tax}}</td>' +
                        '<td>{{x.quantity}}</td>' +
                        '<td>{{ (x.price + x.tax) * x.quantity }}</td>' +
                    '</tr>' +
                    '</tbody>' +
                    '</table>' +
                    '</div>';

        //$compile()($scope)
        return template;
    }
}
```

Here is my directive:

```
app.directive('headerKEditor', function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
            elem.keditor({
                isHeader: true,
                invoiceTemplate: scope.templateIntegration()
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Here is how this directive is being used:

```
<div id="wrapper">
                    <h3>Repeating Header on Each Page</h3>
                    <div class="invoice-container" header-k-editor></div>
                </div>
```

When I use this html in my preloaded html it shows only {{}} braces without value. I know I am late using the model in controller. But What can be the work around? I used $compile but it did not work on tables with ng-repeat.

Comment: the version of angular?

Comment: @alpha its angular js 1

Comment: Be aware that the `ng-repeat` directive builds DOM asynchronously *after* the function enclosing the $compile completes. If you want to construct DOM for use by a jQuery plugin, use jQuery. jQuery is very good at creating DOM synchronously.

Comment: @georgeawg I tried compiling but it gives me array. I need same string of html node as I am currently assigning to `template` variable, but with actual values instead of {{}}. 
Please help me I am much stuck here.

Comment: The array that $compile returns is a jQuery/JQlite array. For more information on jqLite and its methods, see [AngularJS angular.element API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angular-s-jqlite).

Comment: is there any way that I use this html with model values instead of `{{}}` braces? Actually I don't want to compile my html.

Comment: The [scope.$eval method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval) can be used to synchronously evaluate Angular Expressions. The $compile service returns jQuery elements that are hooked into the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle. Interpolated values with mustaches `{{}}` are queued to be evaluated later *asynchronously* by the framework.

Comment: Hi @Umar, I will be appreciated if you share your angularjs directive for kEditor